# Convert PIL int32 to Float64

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

If I load a grayscale image with PIL:

```py
>from PIL import Image
>import numpy as np
>
>img = Image.open('grayscale.png')
```

It will return as int32:

```py
>np.array(img).dtype
dtype('int32')
```

And for the particular Image I got typical min and max Values:

```py
>np.array(img).max()
65535
>np.array(img).min()
2580
```

But if I now cast the grayscale to rgb weird things are happen:

```py
>casted_img = img.convert('RGB')
>np.array(casted_img).dtype
dtype('uint8')
>np.array(casted_img).max()
255
>np.array(casted_img).min()
255
```

It seems it just dumps the pixel values into uint8 loosing all entropy. So further converting to float64 doesn't makes any sense.

I have no issue doing the math myself, but I thought this is something already existing.

Or is PIL not the right tool for the job?

Comment: PIL's RGB mode is 24-bit — 3 x 8-bit components.

Comment: Yes I know that, but the conversion is doing stupid stuff I don't understand. I did Type Conversions by hand many times. But I couldn't wrap around what pillow is doing. At the moment I am down the River and do the work by hand again. Thought it would be cleaner to work with existing methods...

Comment: What is it that you are actually hoping to do, please? You currently have a single channel of 16-bit data. Making it into int32, or float64 or RGB isn't going to give you anything more than what you already have.

Comment: The Images are used in a network which expects RGB images. I know that I don't get more information. So instead of reworking the network and having probably issues with pretrained weights it is easier to load the images as pseudo RGB.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the image as a float64 typed matrix like so:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('grayscale.png')
img_matrix = np.array(img).astype(float64)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. But sorry that will not work. It seems to be the easy answer to my question but actually just casting the values. A Float representation of an image is either between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1. I now how to achieve this with numpy arrays, but I somehow hoped an image library as PIL would provide decent converting methods to create RGB float images from grayscale images.

Comment: @MaKaNu It is not necessarily correct that a float representation of an image is in one of the two ranges you suggest. They can take any value representable by float.

Comment: @Mark Setchell from the data pov this is correct, but also it is not standadized that float or double representation of an Image are between range(0,1) or range(-1, 1) it is mostly the case.